# Grouping data frame variables in a table with subheader

Tags: r, dataframe

I aim to produce a publication-quality table with the output of a data frame. The table should contain two levels of column headers. Thus, variables should be grouped and have a common upper level of heading. Imagine that the data frame looks like this one:

```
df<-data.frame(Names=c(w,x,y,z), A_one=c(1,2,3,4), A_two=c(2,3,4,5), B_one=c(3,4,5,6), B_two=c(4,5,6,7))
```

I would like to have a table like this (sorry for the very poor handmade example;-):

```
|Names|A        |B        |
|     |one |two |one |two |
|w    |1   |2   |3   |4   |
|x    |2   |3   |4   |5   |
|y    |3   |4   |5   |6   |
|z    |4   |5   |6   |7   |
```

Do you know any simple way?

Comment: If this is to produce a table for a presentation or paper, take a look at the `xtable` package. There are a couple of posts on SO for how to do this with `xtable`.

Comment: Do you want the output to be an html table?

Comment: I need the table for a paper publication. I do not use LaTex.

Comment: So would you be able to use html to embed the table to your paper publication? You need to tell us what you would like the output to be.

Comment: I am not sure but I guess that I can embed a html table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tableHTML` to create a table like this.

You could do:

```
library(tableHTML)
names(df) <- c(' ', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two')
tableHTML(df, 
          rownames = FALSE,
          second_header = list(c(1, 2, 2), c('Names', 'A', 'B')),
          widths = rep(50, 5),
          theme = 'scientific')
```

Which Outputs:

[image]

I am using the scientific theme above, but you can choose a different one you like or you could create your own using the `add_css_*` functions.

There is [this tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html) you can see on how to use the package.

In case you want to see the HTML code behind the table (so that you can embed it manually for example) you just use `print`:

```
mytable <- tableHTML(df, 
          rownames = FALSE,
          second_header = list(c(1, 2, 2), c('Names', 'A', 'B')),
          widths = rep(50, 5),
          theme = 'scientific')

print(mytable, viewer = FALSE)
```

The code can also be exported with `write_tableHTML` too.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! I only have two objections: 1) Once adding the second header I should change the name of the "first headers". How can I do it? I cannot change them before, because otherwise data frame variables would have the same name (one, two, one, two), which is not possible. 2) I think I could manage to have a html table, but is there any other likely output/format using this or other package? I am using R markdown for a very first draft and MS Word for writing the paper.

Comment: As you can see in my answer above I changed the first headers first and I had duplicate column names. You can do that. If you use Rmarkdown you could export it normally in pdf. `tableHTML` works fine with that. You can use html tables in word as well. If you google that you can find many related posts. If you want to build a table to use in a paper, html is the best choice (otherwise you would need to do it manually in excel and copy paste it).

Comment: Thanks! By chance I found the package htmlTable. Is there any difference with tableHTML? Any reason for using one instead of the other?

Comment: I ended up developing `tableHTML` because `htmltable` wouldn't let me format the tables in the way I wanted :) Hope that's a good enough reason.